# interceptor не перехватывает ошибку

Tags: angular

есть interceptor в котором нужно обрабатывать 401( Unauthorized) ошибку

```
 return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
                 return this.handle401Error(req, next);
}
              return throwError(error);
```

почему-то 401 не отлавливается, хотя в браузере ее видно
В чем может быть дело?
[image: chrome dev output]

Comment: Создай пожалуйста пример на codesandbox, это во1х. Во2х - что значит "не отлавливается"? событие приходит в catchError?

Comment: @overthesanity , не отлаливается - ошибка приходит в catchError, но статус у нее 0, в браузере видно, что от сервера приходит 401

Comment: но ты ведь этого не сказал, верно? :D

Comment: это известная проблема и связана она с CORSами

Comment: то место куда ты стучишься не возвращает нужные хедеры браузеру, и это видно в response headers

Comment: @overthesanity, понял, а как узнать каких хедеров браузеру не хватает?

Comment: ему нужен `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, можешь почитать об этом на MDN. Я ж не знаю что у тебя на серверной стороне

Comment: @overthesanity , заголовок получил, теперь в catchError ничего не попадает( в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в том как ты сеттишь этот заголовок, что у тебя на стороне сервера?

Comment: @overthesanity, сори, все хорошо, все попадает, думаю, можно закрывать вопрос, спасибо за помощь

Comment: ты можешь оставить ответ сам на свой вопрос тут и пометить его галочкой через какое-то время, чтоб он не висел без ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема с cors, сервер не отдавал  Access-Control-Allow-Origin заголовок